# android wifi permission

Tags: android, wifi

I don't understand why i need to add WAKE_LOCK permission to the application manifest when I toggle wifi with setWifiEnabled... 
Any idea ?

Comment: no, i had this exception on my phone (HTC Magic)

Answer (score 3):

Just a guess, but I'd imagine it's because wifi is pretty power hungry, and wake locks are Android's mechanism to help the system manage when apps are using power. From http://pdk.android.com/online-pdk/guide/power_management.html:

> A locked wakelock, depending on its type, prevents the system from entering suspend or other low-power states.